# How to use classpath to specify a file location?

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

Here is the structure of my maven project:

main and test folders are under src folder, java and resources folders are under main folder, 
in the resources folder, there is a csv file ready for reading.

```
src  
  --main  
    |-- java  
    |-- resources  
           |-- test.csv
test
```

As far as I know,
`InputStream file = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("test.csv");`
could get the file content in the resources file.

However, in order to read and parse csv file based on supercsv library,  I have to use the following code, but InputStream is not acceptable by CsvBeanReader method.

```
beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader(CSV_FILENAME), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
```

**So How can I not only getting the file from resource folder based on the maven structure, but also CsvBeanReader could accept the argument passed in.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) instead of `FileReader`.

This is possible because the constructor of [`CsvBeanReader`](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/io/CsvBeanReader.html) accepts the abstract class [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html):

```
CsvBeanReader(Reader reader, CsvPreference preferences)
//Constructs a new CsvBeanReader with the supplied Reader and CSV preferences.
```

You can construct the `InputStreamReader` using the `InputStream` you have obtained:

```
InputStreamReader(InputStream in)
InputStreamReader(InputStream in, Charset cs)
InputStreamReader(InputStream in, CharsetDecoder dec)
InputStreamReader(InputStream in, String charsetName)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the `java.io.InputStream` with a `java.io.InputStreamReader` (which extends `java.io.Reader`) and pass it to the `CsvBeanReader` class.